# How to count expiry date when we enter month in odoo 13

Tags: python

Requirement is when we enter purchase `Date` (like 06/01/2020) and `month` (like 14).

It will count expire date from purchase date, so the `warranty_expires_on` `Date` (like 07/31/2021).

I have added field in version 13 which is

```
purchase_date=fields.Date(string="Purchase Date")

warranty_period=fields.Integer(string="Warranty Period")

warranty_expires_on=fields.Date(string="Warranty Expires on",compute="_get_date",store=True)

unit_of_time = fields.Selection([

        (YEARLY, 'Years'),
        (MONTHLY, 'Months'),
        (WEEKLY, 'Weeks')])
count = fields.Integer(string="Number of ranges to generate", required=True,default=1)

@api.depends('purchase_date','warranty_period')

def _get_date(self):
    for rec in self:
        vals = rrule(freq=rec.unit_of_time, 
                    interval=rec.warranty_period,
                    dtstart=rec.purchase_date,
                    count=rec.count+1)
        vals = list(vals)
        for idx, dt_start in enumerate(vals[:-1]):
            purchase_date = dt_start.date()
            warranty_expires_on = vals[idx+1].date() - relativedelta(days=1)
            rec.update({'warranty_expires_on':warranty_expires_on})
```

from xml side...

```
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='warranty_period']" position="after">
                <field name="unit_of_time"/>
            </xpath>


            <xpath expr="//field[@name='unit_of_time']" position="after">
                <field name="count" invisible='1'/>
            </xpath>
```

But i am facing below error.

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 619, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 309, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 664, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 345, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/service/model.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 338, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 909, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 510, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1319, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1311, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/api.py", line 395, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/api.py", line 382, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/models.py", line 6062, in onchange
    for name in nametree

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/models.py", line 6063, in <listcomp>
    if name not in done and snapshot0.has_changed(name)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/models.py", line 5930, in has_changed
    return self[name] != record[name]

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/models.py", line 5589, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/fields.py", line 973, in __get__
    self.compute_value(recs)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/fields.py", line 1087, in compute_value
    records._compute_field_value(self)

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/odoo_13/odoo/models.py", line 3905, in _compute_field_value
    getattr(self, field.compute)()

  File "/home/yash/Workspace/project13/equipment_allocations_app/models/maintenance.py", line 68, in _get_date
    count=rec.count+1)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 619, in __init__

    if freq < HOURLY:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: How you defined `YEARLY`?

Answer (score 0):

[rrule freq](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html#classes) argument must be one of YEARLY, MONTHLY, WEEKLY, DAILY, HOURLY, MINUTELY, or SECONDLY.

```
(YEARLY,
 MONTHLY,
 WEEKLY,
 DAILY,
 HOURLY,
 MINUTELY,
 SECONDLY) = list(range(7))
```

`freq` must  be in `list(range(7))`

```
>>> from dateutil.rrule import MONTHLY
>>> MONTHLY
1
```

Odoo will raise an error if you try to use values in selection of type different from `str`,

```
AssertionError: Field purchase.order.unit_of_time with non-str value in selection - - -
```

Get the integer freq using the selection value

**Example**

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, YEARLY, MONTHLY, WEEKLY

unit_of_time = fields.Selection([

    (str(YEARLY), 'Years'),
    (str(MONTHLY), 'Months'),
    (str(WEEKLY), 'Weeks')])
```

Convert `unit_of_time` to `int` when calling `rrule`

```
freq=int(rec.unit_of_time)
```